# extracting two text value from html elements with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

Using cheerio, $ is defined as cheerio object, I am trying to get two text (Current price and Original Price) from some elements which have only class no id defined in a html. Any clue how to achieve this ?

Here is the snippet of the html content which hold this two values,

```
<div class="buy-box__element">
   <div class="clp-component-render">
      <div class="clp-component-render">
         <div class="ud-component--course-landing-page-udlite--price-text" ng-non-bindable="">
            <div>
               <div class="price-text--container--Ws-fP udlite-clp-price-text" data-purpose="price-text-container">
                  <div class="price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xl" data-purpose="course-price-text"><span class="udlite-sr-only">Current price</span><span><span>₹700</span></span></div>
                  <div class="price-text--price-part--Tu6MH price-text--original-price--2e-F5 udlite-clp-list-price udlite-text-sm" data-purpose="original-price-container">
                     <div data-purpose="course-old-price-text"><span class="udlite-sr-only">Original Price</span><span><s><span>₹1,280</span></s></span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-percent-discount udlite-text-sm" data-purpose="discount-percentage"><span class="udlite-sr-only">Discount</span><span>45% off</span></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With X-path it is working,but I want to achieve this with cheerio. also tried with following

```
#(".price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xl udlite-sr-only")[0].innerText
#(".price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xl udlite-sr-only")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$('span:contains("Current price") + span span').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

the `html` should be the inner html, you can use puppeteer like libraries.Something like `let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);`

```
$('span:contains("Current price")', html).each(function() {
        let CurrentPrice1 = $(this).next().text();
        let CurrentPrice2 = Number(CurrentPrice1.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
        console.log(CurrentPrice1); //this with symbol
        console.log(CurrentPrice2); //this for only fetching the numeric value
    });
```

for Original price replace Current price with Original Price